# Revision selection in git using fork-point

Tags: git

Suppose I say `A..B`. From [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

> The most common range specification is the double-dot syntax. This
>   basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable
>   from one commit but aren’t reachable from another.

Let us say, a graph like this:

```
* c6ddc03 (HEAD -> topic) t6
* 11751b7 t5
*   a1c4ed2 Merge branch 'small_topic1' into topic
|\  
| * 7bc86ff s2
| * e1b1384 s1
* | 9582f60 t4
* | 815137a t3
|/  
* 648741c t2
* cfce615 t1
| * 7e46c48 (master) m2
| * 84a4dc7 m3
|/  
* 2d15aa1 1
```

If I say what is `7bc86ff..c6ddc03` , then I get

```
c6ddc037e9e67647ae69e213c0c5b8a29f5d2745
11751b72f943c4daeb9f28a8dddd93a4b98cb8dc
a1c4ed284557cde1e1474bc5e3f7ef0cd7008ba8
9582f60bf9e5464254a51cb6a085d41005f5795f
815137ac9cbe51768cdaf4c27200f51ecad27fbb
```

Clearly, this tells us that `A..B` does not take merge-base (which is `7bc86ff` in figure above) into consideration.
Because if we had defined `A..B` as - All commits of B from merge-base of A and B , then this definition wont give above answer.

[image]

My question is when we say `git rebase --fork-point A B` uses fork-point to evaluate `A..B`, then is not it wrong ? When even merge-base does not effect `A..B` selection , how can fork-point be used for it ?

---

For those who want above commit graph in local, run this script

```
#!/bin/bash

git init .
echo "10" >> 1.txt && git add . && git commit -m "1"

# Add 2 commits to master
echo "3" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "m3"
echo "2" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "m2"


#checkout topic branch
git checkout -b topic HEAD~2
echo "1" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "t1"
echo "2" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "t2"
echo "1" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "t3"
echo "2" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "t4"


#checkout small_topic
git checkout -b small_topic1 HEAD~2
echo "1" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "s1"
echo "2" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "s2"

git checkout topic
git merge small_topic1
echo "1" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "t5"
echo "2" >> 1.txt && git commit -am "t6"

git branch -D small_topic1

#Show graph
git log --oneline --all --decorate --graph
```

Comment: I find the `--fork-point` option difficult to comprehend, much less explain, but essentially it replaces the `<upstream>` limiter inside rebase with one chosen by whatever `git merge-base --fork-point` prints. The result of `git merge-base --fork-point` depends on what is in a reflog and is therefore quite obscure. The situation is a little better today than it was earlier, because you can at least run your own `git merge-base --fork-point` command, but now that rebase is all in C code, it's not obvious what arguments to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^A` says ~no commits currently reachable from `A`~.

`A..B` is syntax sugar for, gets rewritten as, `^A B`, so it's ~commits currently reachable from `B`, except nothing currently reachable from `A`~.

`--fork-point` effectively says "hunt through the reflogs and exclude all commits that were *ever* reachable using excluded refnames".

Keep in mind that Git exists to do useful things to a simple structure: a dag of snapshots.  `--fork-point` was the name someone came up with for ~they rebased the upstream branch, I want to rebase just my stuff onto the new tip, not the stuff upstream used to refer to but abandoned, so to do that I hunt through the reflogs and snip-snip-snip at all the old tips~.

> My question is when we say `git rebase --fork-point A B` uses fork-point to evaluate `A..B`, then is not it wrong ?

Why?  Fork-point with those args means ~`A..B` and additionally truncate at any historical `A` tip~. Is that not what you want?

---

> Clearly [...] A..B does not take merge-base (which is 7bc86ff in figure above) into consideration.

That is not true, because

> Because if we had defined A..B as - All commits of B from merge-base of A and B , then this definition wont give above answer.

That's not the only way to take the merge base into consideration.  You're layering far too much characterization and abstraction on top of a very simple underlying concrete reality: a dag of snapshots.  The merge base of two tips is by definition reachable from both, so `^A B` most definitely does consider the merge base. Twice, even.

Comment: What do you mean by `~` notation like `~no commits` or `A~` ?

Comment: It's a paraphrase quote, meaning "the words are close enough to get the gist, it's close enough but might miss irrelevant details".

Comment: Thnx for the reply. I understand the concept behind fork-point. My question is how does answer change for evaluating `A..B` if we use with or without fork-point ? Is not still `A..B` means , as you said , `commits currently reachable from B, except nothing currently reachable from A.`

Comment: "Fork-point with those args means ~`A..B` and additionally truncate at any historical `A` tip~.".

Comment: If I am getting this right, by `..truncate at any historical A tip` , you mean that `remove` all those commits where A tip has been from the sets of commit obtained by `A..B` . Correct ?

Comment: Yep. That's it.  Not just the ones currently in its history, the ones that were in its history before.

Comment: Let me run `git rebase --fork-point A B`. If there is no force push on my `A` branch , then --fork-point will behave as normal rebase only when used ? Because any historical tip of A will be in this case already excluded in `A..B`. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct, when you start tracking local branches there's local equivalents of force pushes, it's the abandoned-history part that fork-point's meant for.